# UITableView freezes after deleting an entry

Tags: uitableview, swift

My app's MasterView includes a table view which is filled with 10 cells containing some core data objects like a "title" (previously downloaded from the internet, see next paragraph). Thanks to the template "Master-Detail Application" I can make use of the built-in NSFetchedResultsController and its methods which take care of the core data handling (e.g. deleting rows). When running the app, the cells get configured with the existent core data objects. At this point I can delete those entries like one would expect.

In addition, my app also has a refresh button. When tapped, it loads some new data from the internet and converts it into objects that are saved to core data. The cells configure themselves again the same way they did before and the UITableView gets a refresh. Again I can delete an entry but now, as soon as I've deleted one which then disappears normally, the table freezes (not the whole app) in the sense that its cells are not tappable anymore/don't react to gestures. I can refresh and that work (10 entries again after having deleted one before) but the cells keep being untappable. I have to stop the app to return to normal functionality.

When restarting, the one entry deleted before is - like expected - gone, 9 entries are left. Again everything works fine at this point, I can delete multiple ones without a problem. But as soon as a manual refresh took place, we're at the same point as before when deleting an entry now.

A common pattern when missing something specific? I'm happy to post some code but I have no idea right now which parts would help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the app is really freezing, common sources of this sort of problem are [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). If you're using `dispatch_sync` anywhere, that's a common source of problems (notably using `dispatch_sync` from the main thread to something that eventually does another `dispatch_sync` back to the main thread). If you're using `NSLock` or `@synchronized`, and call them recursively, you can also deadlock that way, too.

Another source of problem is an infinite loop (such as an error in a `while` clause that is never satisfied). If you have such a loop in the main thread, that will freeze the UI. (Anything that blocks the main thread will freeze the UI.)

You might be able to diagnose where it's freezing by running the app through the debugger in Xcode, and when the app freezes, press the debugger's "pause" button. While it will often pause in the middle of some fairly cryptic assembler code, you can often look at the stack traces to figure out where the app was when it froze.

---

If it's simply that you're not seeing your UI updated as a result of your actions, try making sure that the `reloadData` method is called on the main queue, if it's not, e.g.:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I have no dispatches in my code so far, neither NSLocks or similar. Also there is no while loop. What I don't get, is, why it works before refreshing but not after even though the cells are filled the same way through core data and show up correctly after the refresh and are tappable too - everything works besides deleting. Actually then just the table freezes but not the whole app (refresh button still tappable even though it has, now, no influence anymore on the table).

Comment: Could it be a problem that - **when refreshing** - the following processes `savingNewObjectsToCoreData` as well as `numbersOfSectionsInRows`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `configureCell` now **aren't** running on main thread anymore (tested with `NSThread.isMainThread()`) whereas they always are when starting the app? (The saving to core data excluded as there is no need it no refresh takes place)

Comment: EDIT 1. comment: I can still tap the refresh button (after the table freezed) and the table **gets refreshed**, so 10 items again whereas it was 9 before (after deletion of one). But still, the table cells themselves are not tappable/don't react to gestures anymore...

Comment: You might try making sure that your `[tableView reloadData]` is dispatched to the main queue (if you happen to be doing it from a background queue), as that's what generally triggers all of those other methods. In the absence of code (and I understand why you didn't want to bury us in a ton of code, probably most of which would be unrelated to the problem), it's hard to say...

Comment: Rob, thanks! You pushed me towards the right direction. I checked the very bottom of the pre-built code looking for the reloadData(). In controllerDidChangeContent: There was a .endUpdates() but not a .reloadData(). I first didn't care about it because 1. it was pre-built like that 2. everything was working before I start rebuilding several parts of the app. It's even commented there that if a large number of changes are made simultaneously, it can have performance implications. If that happens one should add a .reloadData() ...I'm wondering why it was not implemented right away.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if related, but I run into a freezing problem with table view with header and footer view that were reloaded manually after Core Data fetch request. Table view was reloaded right after the fetch and sometimes was stopping respond to touches. Delaying the tableView.reloadData() by 0.1 second fixed the problem completely.

(Without header and footer view, everything worked fine).